# Rails Bootstrap_Form Collection Select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to get my bootstrap_form collection_select to work, but I am having some difficulty. I am using Bootstrap 4 for context.

I have a collection of Tags, and I would like the user to be able to select multiple tags to add to a single Event. I cannot select multiple tags. Currently, the select appears with the valid options in the select. I am also having an issue with my submit.

_form.html.erb:

```
<%= f.collection_select :tags, Tag.all, :id, :name,  hide_label: true, options: { placeholder: "Tag Id", multiple: true}, html_options: { input_group_class: 'input-group-lg' } %>
```

Events_controller.rb (Controller):

```
  def create
    @event = Event.new(event_params)
    respond_to do | format |
      if @event.save
        results = Geocoder.search(@event.location)
        lat, long = results.first.coordinates
        @event.location_lat = lat
        @event.location_long = long
        @event.save
        UserEventRelationship.create(event_id: @event.id, user_id: current_user.id, role_type_id: 0)
        format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @event, status: :created, location: @event }
      else
        format.html {render 'new'}
        format.json {render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Event.rb (Model):

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :user_event_relationships
    has_many :users, through: :user_event_relationships
    has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
    has_one_attached :picture
    validates :name, :location, :date_to, :date_from, presence: true
    validate :valid_date_range_required
end
```

Tag.rb:

```
class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :events
end
```

Join Table Migration:

```
class CreateJoinTableEventsTags < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_join_table :events, :tags do |t|
       t.index [:event_id, :tag_id]
       t.index [:tag_id, :event_id]
    end
  end
end
```

Error:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `each' for "10":String:
  app/controllers/events_controller.rb:30:in `create'
```

Comment: Which line is line 30 in your events controller?

Comment: @event = Event.new(event_params)

Comment: If it is a bootstrap problem, show the entire `_form.html.erb`. Also, what are the tags for?

Comment: Can you post your whole controller file please. It looks like a problem with your `event_params` method

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue! I had to not permit tags as a param in event_params, shown here:

```
      params.require(:event).permit(:name, :date_from,
      :location, :date_to, :description, :picture)
```

Instead, I wrote some code in my create controller which found the tags from the tags field, and then added them to the @event.tags.

Here is that code:

```
def create
    tags = Tag.find(params.require(:event)['tags'])
    #puts "Params: #{params}"
    @event = Event.new(event_params)
    respond_to do | format |
      if @event.save
        results = Geocoder.search(@event.location)
        lat, long = results.first.coordinates
        @event.location_lat = lat
        @event.location_long = long
        tags.each {|tag|
          @event.tags << tag
        }
        #@event.save
        UserEventRelationship.create(event_id: @event.id, user_id: current_user.id, role_type_id: 0)
        format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @event, status: :created, location: @event }
      else
        format.html {render 'new'}
        format.json {render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```